# merging 2 lists into 1 with logic

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 lists of the same type.

List 1:

- ID
- Name
- Value

> 1,"Prod1", 0
>   2,"Prod2", 50
>   3,"Prod3", 0

List 2:

- ID
- Name
- Value

> 1,"Prod1", 25
>   2,"Prod2", 100
>   3,"Prod3", 75

I need to combine these 2 lists into 1, but I only want the values from list2 if the corresponding value from list1 == 0

So my new list should look like this:

> 1,"Prod1", 25
>   2,"Prod2", 50
>   3,"Prod3", 75

I've tried many variations of something like this:

```
var joined = from l1 in List1.Where(x=>x.Value == "0")
join l2 in List2 on l1.ID equals l2.ID into gj
select new { gj };
```

I've also tried a variation of the `concat`

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to select the individual properties and conditionally select either the `Value` from the first or second list item.

```
var List1 = new[]
            {
                new { Name = "Prod1", Id = 1, Value = 0 },
                new { Name = "Prod2", Id = 2, Value = 50 },
                new { Name = "Prod3", Id = 3, Value = 0 },
                new { Name = "NotInList2", Id = 4, Value = 0}
            };
var List2 = new[]
            {
                new { Name = "Prod1", Id = 1, Value = 25 },
                new { Name = "Prod2", Id = 2, Value = 100 },
                new { Name = "Prod3", Id = 3, Value = 75 }
            };

var results = from l1 in List1
              join l2temp in List2 on l1.Id equals l2temp.Id into grpj
              from l2 in grpj.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new
              {
                  l1.Id,
                  l1.Name,
                  Value = l1.Value == 0 && l2 != null ? l2.Value : l1.Value
              };

foreach(var item in results)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Will output

> { Id = 1, Name = Prod1, Value = 25 }
>
> { Id = 2, Name = Prod2, Value = 50 }
>
> { Id = 3, Name = Prod3, Value = 75 }
>
> { Id = 4, Name = NotInList2, Value = 0 }

NOTE: This assumes that you only want all the ids that are in `List1` (not any that are only in `List2`) and that the ids are unique and that the `Name` from `List1` is what you want even if it is different in `List2`.

Comment: Thanks!  This is what I needed.  How would it change if the lists were different?

Comment: @webdad3 Well if you wanted all the items in List1, replacing the zero values from List2, but some of the ids in List1 might not be in List2, then you'd want to do a left join `join l2a in List2 on l1.Id equals l2a.Id into grpj from l2 in grpj.DefaultIfEmpty()` then just change the conditional to `Value = l1.Value == 0 && l2 != null ? l2.Value : l1.Value`

Answer (score 1):

clone l1 and

```
foreach (var item in l1Clone)
    if (item.value == 0)
        item.value == l2.FirstOrDefault(l2item => l2item.ID == item.ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the code below:

```
IEnumerable<item> join_lists(IEnumerable<item> list1, IEnumerable<item> list2)
{
  var map = list2.ToDictionary(i => i.id);
  return list1.Select(i => new item()
  {
    id = i.id,
    name = i.name,
    value = i.value == 0 ? map[i.id].value : i.value
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var combined = list1
    .Zip(list2, (product1, product2) => product1.Value == 0 ? product2 : product1);
```